# как сделать постраничный вывод с категорией

Tags: php, mysql

есть две таблицы "countrys" со столбцами id и country, id для каждой страны своё, и вторая таблица "citys" со столбцами id, city и countri_id, последний это id страны. Так же есть сайт с drop down menu в котором список стран, при нажатии на страну  , переходит на сайт со списком всех городов этой страны, страница сравнивает полученный ID по GET и выдает список нужных городов, а как теперь сделать не весь список, а скажем только по 5 городов на страницу не понимаю. Сделал другой сайт  с полным списком городов и в нем постраничный вывод всё норм, а как теперь в него засунуть еще и выбор страны не понимаю

Comment: https://www.native-english.ru/grammar/english-nouns-plural - это ссылка не ответ на ваш вопрос, но тоже не менее полезная:)

Comment: ландан из зе кепитал оф грейт британ) спасибо, буду знать)))